# Apache https to http redirect

Tags: apache-2.4, redhat, reverse-proxy, redirect

I am trying to route https traffic through another server that has a tomcat server. Before i was just using http and was working fine.

My conf reads

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ProxyRequests on
             ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:80/
             ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:80/
             ProxyPreserveHost On
             SSLEngine on
             ServerName support.address.co.uk
             SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/support_address_co_uk.crt
             SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/support.address.co.uk.key 
 </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
          ProxyRequests on
          ProxyPass / balancer://myBalancer/ stickysession=JSESSIONID scolonpathdelim=On
          ProxyPassReverse / balancer://myBalancer/

          <Proxy balancer://myBalancer >
             BalancerMember http://tomcat:90 route=tomcatA loadfactor=100
          </Proxy>

             RewriteEngine On

             RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(.*)$
             RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=SERVER_NAME:%1,NS]
             RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^(.*)$
             RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=SERVER_PORT:%1,NS]
             RequestHeader set X-Remote-Address "%{SERVER_NAME}e:%{SERVER_PORT}e"


 </VirtualHost>
```

If i try this it just changes the traffic from https to http and continues using http once i have proceeded past the login page.  How can I change it so that i keep the https once it comes back ?

I have tried to put another rewrite rule in and receive the error to many redirects.

Cheers.

Comment: so you do a login on HTTP and want to switch back to HTTPS afterwards? i smell security by obscurity here

Comment: Sorry I login with https:// problem the connection just stays http.